# Magento 2 How to select fields in query

Tags: magento2, database, customer, data

I'm using below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select()
        ->from(
        ['ce' => 'customer_entity']
);
$data = $connection->fetchAll($select);
```

It's working fine. It returns all customer fields. I would like to select only First Name, Last Name & Email.

Instead of select(), which function we need to use & how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$select = $connection->select()
    ->from(
        ['ce' => 'customer_entity'],
        ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']
    );
$data = $connection->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: How will we add where condition in this?

Comment: @AmritPalSingh - Taking reference from Sohel Rana's query
after select statement(& before fetchAll) you can add
where clause ie. $select->where('customer_id = ?', (int)$cust_id);

Comment: How can you make the select distinct?

Answer (score 3):

Use below code for select particular field from database table.

> File path: magento/app/code/Venodr/ModuleName/Model/CustomerData.php

```
<?php

namespace Venodr\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;

class CustomerData
{
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    )
    {
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    }

    public function getQueryData()
    { 
        $query = $this->connection->fetchAll("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM customer_entity");
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = $adapter->select()
    ->from(
        ['c' => $tableName],
        ['*','total' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('c.qty + c.sale_qty')]
    );
```

Comment: Self blog promotion is not allowed